# How to "completely" close page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm making a request to a rest API with the getData function (see code). If for some reason the request fails I call the getData function again until it succeeds.

The problem is: If i pop the page, the requests will still get sent (the loop will still be running).

How do I close the page so the code execution stops? Right now I am using pop to close the page.

```
// Imports ...

export class RecipePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: HttpClient)
    {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/get/recipes')
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log('retrying ...');

                    // !! This loop continues after the page is popped !!
                    setTimeout( () => {
                        this.getData();
                    }, 2000);
                },
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout` to *clear* that `setTimeout` when leaving that page:

```
// Imports ...

export class RecipePage {

    private timeout: any;

    constructor(...) {}

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        // Try to get the data when entering to the page
        this.getData();
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        // Clear the timeout to prevent making request after leaving the page
        if(this.timeout) {                
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        }
    }

    getData() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/get/recipes')
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log('retrying ...');

                    if(this.timeout) {
                        // Prevent multiple setTimeouts at the same time
                        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
                    }

                    // Store a reference in the timeout property
                    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => { this.getData(); }, 2000);
                },
            );
    }
}
```

Please also notice a few things:

1. It's not recommended to make an http request in the `constructor`. Use `IonViewWillLoad`/`IonicViewWillEnter`/... or any other lifecycle hook instead
2. When you get an error in the request, check if there's a setTimeout already running before creating a new one. That way you could avoid multiple setTimeouts running at the same time.
3. Using a `setTimeout` is not the best way to retry an http request if it fails. Please take a look at **[this blog post](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/retrying-http-requests-with-rxjs)** to see how you could **Retry Http Requests With RxJs**

Comment: So there is no way to just stop all code execution in that class? Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by *stop all code execution in that class*? @oskarzimmerman